# Sequence contains no elements with LINQ FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm getting 'Sequence contains no elements' with LINQ FirstOrDefault.

```
int? locationId = _ctx.m_locations.FirstOrDefault(
                       l => l.name.ToLower() == countyOrTown.ToLower()
                  ).location_key;
```

I thought the whole point of FirstOrDefault is that it doesn't raise an exception if there are no entries in the database and just returns null?

Comment: Even so, how do you expect to access `location_key` successfully when `null` is returned?

Comment: Yes, it will return NULL if there are no elements - and you cannot do a `.location_key` on a NULL value!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since as you say yourself, `.FirstOrDefault()` will return a `NULL` value, you need to first **check** for that NULL and only if it's `NOT NULL` then access it's `.location_key` property:

```
int? locationId = null;

var firstOrDefault = _ctx.m_locations.FirstOrDefault(l => l.name.ToLower() == countyOrTown.ToLower());

if(firstOrDefault != null)
    locationId = firstOrDefault.location_key;
```

Comment: This does not explain why the error is `Sequence contains no elements` and not a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that you're trying to invoke the "location_key" property on an object that potentially is going to be NULL, right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it throws a "Sequence contains [...]" and not a null exception ?

If your query returns indeed "default" (or null here) your code will throw:

(null).location_key

Answer (score 0):

Test m_locations and countyOrTown for null reference, first!  You may not have the object instantiated.

Also, (you probably have already done this) you should verify countyOrTown does not contain an empty string, and that no typos are in the data, resulting in no matches.